# Tomcat won't start: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: tomcat

when I start my locale instance of Tomcat I get the following error:

```
    SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[8005]: 
    java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:359)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:373)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:662)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

I have seen on forums people had the same problem. 
Netstat doesn't show ports 8080, 8005 or 8009 in use. I tried to change port but I get the same error. I've also checked the hosts file in 
Windows\System32\drivers\etc and the line

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

is not commented. I didn't change anything in server.xml and since yesterday I can't get it to work.
Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

Connectors:
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               />

<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: This is not a shutdown problem, it is a startup problem. Probably Tomcat is already running.

Comment: Please post all your <Connector> elements AND the start-element of your <Server> element.

Comment: @rnunes, at the moment I'm not using Tomcat on my local machine

Answer (score 11):

I solved this by specifying

`<Server address="0.0.0.0" port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">`

at conf/server.xml.

Comment: For me actually address="0.0.0.0" was not always working well. I needed to replace the 0.0.0.0 with the ip of network interface (but do not use loopback address 127.0.0.1, use the ip of network card)

Comment: This worked for me with `tomcat-7.0.62` and `macOS Sierra`.

Comment: Cannot use this for tomcat 6.x (hardcoded InetAddress.getByName("localhost")). I know I should've upgraded.

Comment: didn't work for me with `tomcat-8.5.41` and `CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)·

Comment: it worked for me with tomcat 8.5.71 thank you.

Answer (score 8):

the IP of your server has been changed (even IP of other network cards that you don't use) and you have to edit.

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Answer (score 4):

most possible cause is : your IP address for localhost is not confgured correctly in the host file. 
Verify the host file : 
run : system32 : drivers : etc : host 
Open this host file in Notepad

Keep this localhost line as 1st line in the host file. 
Close everything. 
Delete the server from Eclipse and re-configure this. 
It should help.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was the problem with hosts file (windows).
Actually i had the following entry in it from the start ...
    172.16.xxx.yyy  localhost

Some 2 weeks back, there was a physical server and network domain split activity carried out in our company, which changed the IPs of all machines.
Here, my yyy was changed.

When i edited my IP, the error was gone.
Thanks Saurabh Chande for this.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this.

I had the same problem with local tomcat in Eclipse (it wouldn't start because it couldn't find tomcat.bin).
I right clicked on the Tomcat server in Servers tab in Eclipse and clicked properties. At General properties there is a button "Switch Location". It used to point to local Tomcat at Eclipse, but with this button it changed it to the folder on C drive where the actual Tomcat installation is. Now Tomcat is working both in Eclipse and localy.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: Using the proposed solution (server address="0.0.0.0") allows any attacker to remotely shutdown your system.

I propose to use:
< Server address="127.0.0.2" port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN" >

127.0.0.2 will work as a loopback address, but will not interfere with any other service listening at localhost (127.0.0.1)

Comment: With the configuration you propose any **local** attacker can shutdown the server. Currently in most circumstances the server can be shutdown by an OS signal, so the shutdown port can be safely disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue on a server when the permissions on the hosts file were not set up correctly

Running `chmod 644 hosts` corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0):

step 1:
go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

step 2:

find hosts file and open it with notepad with admin mode

step 3:

replace local host ip with 127.0.0.1

example

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

step 4:

save that file and run server

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late to post in this thread but I'd like to help people who come looking for answers and had an issue similar to mine. And I'm unable to comment since I don't have enough reps.

As the OP posted,

> I've also checked the hosts file in Windows\System32\drivers\etc and the line
>
> `127.0.0.1       localhost`
>
> is not commented. I didn't change anything in server.xml and since yesterday I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

I would like to comment on this portion. In my case too, the below line was not commented.

`127.0.0.1 localhost`

However, there was another additional line that was binding the 'localhost' to an old local IP.

`127.0.0.1 localhost
10.10.1.123 localhost`

It was my old local IP that got changed recently due to a router reconfiguration and that was the culprit. So, commenting that duplicate line solved my issue.

The conclusion is, **check if there are multiple bindings for the 'localhost' in addition to checking if the loopback IP is commented.**